# Popping from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I an trying to determine how to remove one or more specific rows from an array of objects.

In the page, I have a text box for user to enter a user ID; click "Find" button and I do a search in AD and add a row to a table with user's display name and user ID. In addition to this, for later processing, I store in an array of objects some info on user in addition to display name and user ID.

Also, I have a checkbox column in above table that user can select and remove one or more of the added users; I can correctly rebuild the table displaying data but don't know how, at this point, remove one or more rows from the array (i.e. the deleted users).

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<table class="adminList" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm delete-admin-row">Delete User(s)</button>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var admins = [];

<Somehow, using ajax, get user's data from AD>

var fn = userData.FirstName;
var mi = userData.Initial;
var ln = userData.LastName;
var name = userData.DisplayName;
var email = userData.Email;
var userid = userData.UserID;

//push the object onto the array
admins.push({
    "fn" : fn,
    "mi" : mi,
    "ln": ln,
    "email": email,
    "userid": userid
});
// Display in admins list
var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + userid + "</td></tr>";
$(".adminList tbody").append(markup);
```

FURTHER DOW IN THE CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete-admin-row").click(function(){
        $(".adminList tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();

                //  HERE I NEED TO POP THE ARRAY
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Not sure if removing the checkbox column and having instead an 'x' image next to each row, associate some property of user data with this 'x' image, say User ID, as 'data-xxx' and accessing it in delete function would be easier; but I still wouldn't know how to access and delete the row from array based on 'userid'.

**Update**

Following the suggestions made, I made the changes but noticed that IE does not understand => nor findIndex. So, I made the following changes but still get -1 as returned index.

```
$(".delete-admin-row").click(function(){
    $(".adminList tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){debugger
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();

            // Both of these return the userid
            const useridToFind1 = this.dataset.userid;
            const useridToFind = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();

            //const index = admins.findIndex(admin => admin.userid === useridToFind);
            const index = admins.indexOf(function (e) { return e.userid === useridToFind });

            if (index !== -1) {    // Always -1
                admins.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the `UserID` to a data attribute of the `input` in a TR, so that when iterating over checked inputs, you can take that value and use `.findIndex` to see if a matching `UserID` object exists in the array. Then you can `splice` it:

```
var markup = "<tr><td><input data-userid='" + userid + "' type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + userid + "</td></tr>";
```

and

```
$(".delete-admin-row").click(function(){
  $(".adminList tbody").find('input[name="record"]:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    const useridToFind = Number(this.dataset.userid);
    const index = admins.findIndex(admin => admin.userid === useridToFind);
    if (index !== -1) {
      admins.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm assuming the userid is a number, thus the need for a type cast in the `.find` (since a `dataset` element will always be a string).

If you have to use an obsolete 7-year-old browser, dumb down the syntax and use a different iteration method:

```
"use strict";

$(".delete-admin-row").click(function() {
  $(".adminList tbody")
    .find('input[name="record"]:checked')
    .each(function() {
      $(this)
        .parents("tr")
        .remove();
      var useridToFind = Number(this.dataset.userid);
      var foundIndex = -1;
      admins.forEach(function(admin, index) {
        if (admin.userid === useridToFind) foundIndex = index;
      });
      if (index !== -1) {
        admins.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a JS syntax error at '>' in findIndex(admin => ...).

Comment: Does your development environment not support arrow functions? They're from ES2015, you should strongly consider upgrading to something more modern

Comment: You can change it to `function(admin) { return admin.userid === useridToFind }` but please upgrade your browser instead

Comment: Found out IE is just too stupid to understand either => or finIndex. So, had to make some changes which I added to "Update" section of original post.

Comment: If you need to support obsolete browsers, use Babel to transpile the code automatically, and use polyfills to add modern objects and methods like `findIndex`. Don't write crappy code just to satisfy IE

Comment: I think it is only IE that is this stupid! And I was testing with IE 11. Am I missing something?

Comment: I found this in SO that suggests using polyfill to get around this. Someone else recommendd against extending built-ins. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938036/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-findindex-ie11-javascript-issue/41938119

Comment: Well, it *was* released 7 years ago. It's to be expected that it has many problems, and there's no good reason to be using IE for web development nowadays. Like I said, best method is to use polyfills and Babel to make modern code compatible with IE.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `splice` method, what you need to know - index of array (first element - 0)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.splice(1, 2); // delete 2 elements starting from second element 
// (second, because first element in array has index - 0, 
// so index 1 - it's second element)

// a will contain -> [1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the user ID from the third `<td>` in the current row. Find the index of the array element with that userid, and remove it with `splice()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete-admin-row").click(function() {
    $(".adminList tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        let userid = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
        let index = admins.findIndex(el => el.userid == userid);
        if (index >= 0) {
          admins.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```